# log4j custom appender not producing any output

Tags: java, logging, log4j, composition

I'm writing a custom appender in log4j that uses composition to wrap another appender (and routes some of the functionality of appenders through the custom one).  Basically, the code looks similar to this:

```
public class CustomAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {
    private Appender target;

    @Override 
    public void activateOptions() {
        super.activateOptions();
        if (target == null) {
            errorHandler.error("Target is null");
        }
    }

    @Override 
    protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {
        if (target == null) {
            errorHandler.error("Target is null");
        } else {
            target.doAppend(this.processEvent(event));
        }
    }

    @Override 
    public void close() {
        if (target != null) target.close();
    }

    public Appender getTarget() {
        return target;
    }

    public void setTarget(Appender target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean requiresLayout() {
        return target == null ? false : target.requiresLayout();
    }
}
```

and I tried setting up the logger in the XML spring configuration like this:

```
...
<prop key="log4j.appender.APPLICATION">CustomAppender</prop>
<prop key="log4j.appender.APPLICATION.Target">org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender</prop>
<prop key="log4j.appender.APPLICATION.Target.DatePattern">...</prop>
...
```

with various other settings for the `DailyRollingFileAppender` and log4j does not produce any output.  However, if I make the class for the `log4j.appender.APPLICATION` a `DailyRollingFileAppender` and essentially remove the keyword `Target.` from each key, it works just fine.

Is there something wrong with how my class is set up?  Did I have a misunderstanding about how the property assignments worked here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the issue goes much deeper, and is in fact linked to the [PropertyConfigurator](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.java.html) class for log4j.  That's where all of the instantiation happens for strings to classes, and I would have to completely rewrite it, it seems, to get something better.